# Why does my C code not produce output?

Tags: c, linux, netbeans, output

In my code I am required to be able to convert any integer input to a desired base between 2 and 16. The problem is though the output states my code runs successfully, i get no output. I have tried in NetBeans and a linux terminal. My code is shown below:

```
/* 
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: Tyler Weaver
 * Assignment 1: Takes a decimal value and converts it to a desired base
 *
 * Created on October 11, 2014, 11:57 PM
 */

#include <stdio.h>

void toBase(unsigned decimal, unsigned base, char *newNum);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const int MAX_LEN = 32;
    char newNum[32];
    unsigned decimal, base;

    printf("Enter a decimal value followed by a desired base: ");
    scanf(" %u", &decimal);
    scanf(" %u", &base);

    toBase(decimal, base, newNum);

    printf("%u equals ", decimal);
    //Print the array out in reverse order
    unsigned count;
    for (count = 0; count != '\0'; count++);
    for (count--; count >= 0; count--) {
        printf("%c", newNum[count]);
    }
    printf(" (base-%u)\n", base);

    return 0;
}

/**
 * Converts a number to desired base
 * @param decimal the number which to convert
 * @param base the base to convert decimal to
 * @param newNum the character array which to store the conversion
 */
void toBase(unsigned decimal, unsigned base, char *newNum) {
    const unsigned ASCII_DIFF = 97;
    char *p;

    for (p = newNum; decimal > 0; p++) {
        unsigned temp = decimal % base;

        *p = (temp < 10) ? temp : ((char) temp - 10 + ASCII_DIFF);
    }
}
```

My output in NetBeans:

```
Enter a decimal value followed by a desired base: 6 4

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s)
```

It appears the same on the linux terminal as well. I have tried placing printf statements after the scanf statements but those do not appear either. Any information would be helpful.

Comment: Um.. `count >= 0` in your for-loop continuation condition? Well, `count` is declared `unsigned count;`. Can you think of *any* time when that condition would *not* be met? (and don't say when `count` is less than zero, because its not signed, so that isn't going to happen).

Comment: What is the intent of `for (p = newNum; decimal > 0; p++)`?  Shouldn't the "while" condition involve `p`?

Comment: If you're looking for the end of newNum, "for (count = 0; count != '\0'; count++);" won't do it. I'm surprised that you're not getting a segmentation fault when count == 0xFFFFFFFF. Hint: 0 == '\0'.

Comment: @RichardPennington I ran the code with the gcc compiler and I did get a segmentation fault. There seems to be alot of issues with this code.

Comment: Your loop in the function is an infinite loop as you never modify `decimal` inside it

Comment: @Cubia The best education is learning how to solve problems. He'll figure it out. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your replies. The problem lied in the multiple infinite loops due to careless programming and incomplete documentation. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be running into an infinite loop inside the toBase function.

```
void toBase(unsigned decimal, unsigned base, char *newNum) {
    const unsigned ASCII_DIFF = 97;
    char *p;

    for (p = newNum; decimal > 0; p++) {
        unsigned temp = decimal % base;

        *p = (temp < 10) ? temp : ((char) temp - 10 + ASCII_DIFF);
    }
}
```

You use `decimal > 0` as a condition, but you never modify the value of decimal inside the loop.

Because of this, all code written after the toBase() function call never gets executed.

Side note : I'm a little bothered by the "RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s)". Compiling this code with GCC and running it gives me a segmentation fault. Combined with the infinite loop issue, I highly doubt that the program has been ended "successfully".

Comment: I ran the code on Netbeans. It gave me a "Ran Successful" although no output. I was thrown off because it said "Ran Successful". I realized all of the infinite loops in my code however, and i thank you.

Comment: In my linux lab it does not say run successful. It just does not show output.*